# Show opened chrome tabs in frames

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to show opened chrome tabs in frames on a single page?
I have already tried to solve this problem with chrome extensions but without success

Comment: Did you check [web extensions tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs)   If you did use that, what actually happened?

Comment: Can you clarify what are you expecting as a help for this question?

Comment: actually this is what I want; I have buttons in the first chrome tab, these buttons open new web pages in new tabs. I want to be able to show these pages in a div or frame on the first tab. So that the user does not have to navigate other tabs

Answer (score 0):

Export Tabs URLs. Extension which displays all tabs urls and titles. Try inpect code for chrome extension.

[Chrome Extension URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-tabs/odafagokkafdbbeojliiojjmimakacil?hl=en)

Comment: As you suggested, I focused on chrome extensions. But I haven't found a solution yet. Thanks MDReal

Comment: It's Help to you?